# jquery.parseJSON not working

Tags: jquery

One of my function returning the following string:

```
{
   "data": [{
      "type": "facebook",
      "id": "639422616",
      "name": "Neal Cabage",
      "message": "Ruby on rails or Sinatra better for a restful app that speaks json, not html?"
   }, {
      "type": "facebook",
      "id": "100001604824773",
      "name": "Christolle Soragee",
      "message": "When you lose: "
      Who cares ? !It 's just a game!" When you win: "HAHAHA IN YOUR FACE LOSER!""},{"type":"facebook","id":"100000049925091","name":"Chris Cassanova Dunphy","message":"It'
      s sad when you already know you 're gonna get ripped off and you have to junkie proof your stash... Hahaha good thing I was on point! It'
      s funny how people with a problem will ruin a good thing just "}]}
```

When i use `jQuery.parseJSON(response)` , it throws exception in some cases when the message have double quotes inside message.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you're getting errors about quotes inside strings, then you're generating the JSON badly. You need to quote the strings you presumably pass to `json_encode()`. Have you tried to solve this issue _at all_ before posting here?

Comment: The problem is that you have to escape some of your "s

Comment: To test your JSON for validity use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It shows that there is an error on line 13.

Answer (score 1):

According to [json.org](http://json.org/):

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.

[image: String]

So, characters such as `"` in the string need to be escaped by a `\`, resulting into something like `"This is my string with a quote \" inside it"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i tried to escape double quotes and single quotes in javascript using replace function like str.replace('\"','\\"'); but nothing works.

Comment: Your JSON also contains newlines. You should also escape them. A better solution would be to find a proper JSON escape method for your framework/language.